# NOT IN sql taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch results from my db, i have following query for it:

```
  SELECT dubaifirstuser.mobile, dubaifirstuser.email, CONCAT( user.fname,  '', user.lname ) AS Name, bank_master.bank_name, bank_master.image, user.createdon
  FROM dubaifirstuser, user, bank_master
  WHERE dubaifirstuser.mobile = user.mobile
  AND bank_master.bank_id = user.bank_id
  AND user.bank_id IN ( 16, 18 )
  AND user.createdon <= '2012-05-31'
  AND dubaifirstuser.mobile NOT IN (SELECT mobile FROM renew_user
  );
```

But it is taking forever to execute, the condition

```
 AND dubaifirstuser.mobile NOT IN (SELECT mobile FROM renew_user
  );
```

is basically taking so much of time rest of the query is getting executed in seconds, as i have thousand of records in table `dubaifirstuser` and `renew_user`, i have tried `NOT EXISTS` in place of `NOT IN` still the execution time is forever, there is no null record in both tables.
Please help how to fetch records faster or with less execution time?

Comment: Do you have any indexes defined on these tables?

Comment: @Oded: No i don't have any indexes define for these tables.

Comment: Time to define some, then.

Comment: @Oded: any other alternative possible, as indexes slow down the insert, update, delete operations, i am not using these tables for search, this query will be a once in long period execution

Comment: I think you need to do some testing. You are not talking about numbers that an index will slow down so much. What amount of inserts/updates/deletes are you expecting (num / sec)?

Comment: Indexes can make your queries run 1000+ times faster and only slightly slow down insert/delete/updates. They can also improve efficiency of some update and delete operations.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks for the help. Indexes are faster anyhow, doesnot matter if they affect other operations or not, no offences for use of indexes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use an OUTER JOIN instead of a NOT IN subquery.

```
  SELECT 
  dubaifirstuser.mobile, 
  dubaifirstuser.email, 
  CONCAT( user.fname,  '', user.lname ) AS Name, 
  bank_master.bank_name,   
  bank_master.image, 
  user.createdon
  FROM dubaifirstuser
  JOIN user ON dubaifirstuser.mobile = user.mobile
  JOIN bank_master ON bank_master.bank_id = user.bank_id
  LEFT JOIN renew_user ON renew_user.mobile = dubaifirstuser.mobile
  WHERE 
  renew_user.mobile IS NULL
  AND user.bank_id IN ( 16, 18 )
  AND user.createdon <= '2012-05-31';
```

Make sure you have a composite index on the user table over (bank_id, createdon,mobile)

Comment: The composite index is optional, but recommended if you want the query to be as fast as possible.  It isn't going to slow down insertions that much to add one index.  If you are that concerned test, don't just assume it will be a whole lot slower, unless it would make the indexes larger than available memory.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, an alternative to `not in` that performs better is to use `not exists`.  Your query is:

```
dubaifirstuser.mobile NOT IN (SELECT mobile FROM renew_user)
```

Instead:

```
not exists (select 1 from renew_user ru where ru.mobile = dubaifirstuser.mobile)
```

The performance will be improved by having an index on `renew_user(mobile)`.  In the first query, it scans `renew_user` for every row being evaluated.  Over and over and over again.

By the way, this is a performance problem with older versions of MySQL.  I believe it has been fixed since the 5.6 release.

Comment: I have already tried using `not exists` as i mentioned in question, it doesn't effect much, using indexes will obviously fast any of the operations using `not in` or `not exists`. Thanks for the help. :)